# Keeping new color while user is online?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I add this line to a link's onClick function .

```html
document.getElementById('a.'+id).style.color= '#414042';
```

When i clicked that link it's color changes but i need to keep this color whenever user is online .While user online he should always see new color not the old color .When user log-out then log-in he should still see new color that he changed  . How can i do this ? In my javascript function .

Comment: If you have some login system than what's your problem?

Comment: how you found out someone is logged in?

Comment: Why does your ID have a period?

Comment: `id`s are allowed to have dots in them. Just makes using them in CSS selectors a pain.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - they can, but man does it seem confusing to have ID's like `a.something` that looks like an anchor with a class ?

Comment: @adeneo: As I said, makes them a pain to use in CSS selectors. :-) But if you only ever use `getElementById` with them and never style them, they're fine.

Comment: When i refreshed the page all color is gone . I need to keep it all time .

Comment: How can i keep it until a second action which i will code .

Comment: T.J. already answered this, you'll need persistent storage, either on the server or in the browser.

Comment: But how can i change color of the link to this new storaged color ? When i refreshed the page color will go again .

Comment: I tried document.getElementById('a.'+id).className= 'clicked'   but it didn't work. It didn't change the style .

Comment: show the relevant html and all relevant javscript. That dot in id is a mystery

Comment: It is not important . What should i use to keep it when i refreshed the page .

Answer (score 2):

You can remember the color in [web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/). From your question, I suspect you'd want `localStorage`, but if you want it automatically cleaned up, then use `sessionStorage` instead.

Saving *(assuming you need to make this `id`-specific)*:

```
localStorage.setItem("color." + id, theirColor);
```

Getting *(same assumption)*:

```
var theirColor = localStorage.getItem("color." + id) || defaultColor;
```

Removing if you have some reason to *(same assumption)*:

```
localStorage.removeItem("color." + id);
```

---

Example ([live copy on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxowh547/1/) — unfortunately, Stack Snippets don't allow use of web storage):

HTML:

```
<label>Pick a color:
  <select id="color-select">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
  </select>
</label>
<div id="target">This is the text</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {
  var color = localStorage.getItem("color") || "red";
  console.log("color = " + color);
  applyColor(color);
  $("#color-select").val(color).on("change", function() {
    var newColor = $(this).val();
    console.log("newColor = " + newColor);
    localStorage.setItem("color", newColor);
      applyColor(newColor);
  });
  function applyColor(color) {
    // Not using jQuery because you mentioned .style.color,
    // but the jQuery way would be $("#target").css("color", color);
    $("#target")[0].style.color = color;
  }
})();
```

---

Original Example, which may have been over-complicated ([live copy on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxowh547/) — unfortunately, Stack Snippets don't allow use of web storage):

HTML:

```
<div>Pick a color:</div>
<div class="colors">
  <div data-color="red"></div>
  <div data-color="blue"></div>
  <div data-color="yellow"></div>
  <div data-color="green"></div>
</div>
<div>Your selected color is shown with a heavy outline.</div>
```

CSS:

```
.colors div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  width: 40px;
  height: 1em;
}

.colors div.selected {
  border: 4px solid black;
}

[data-color=red] {
  background-color: #d00;
}

[data-color=blue] {
  background-color: #00d;
}

[data-color=yellow] {
  background-color: #dd0;
}

[data-color=green] {
  background-color: #0d0;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {
  var color = localStorage.getItem("color") || "red";
  console.log("color = " + color);
  $("[data-color='" + color + "']").addClass("selected");
  $(".colors").on("click", "[data-color]", function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    color = $this.attr("data-color");
    console.log("new color = " + color);
    localStorage.setItem("color", color);
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $this.addClass("selected");
  });
})();
```

Comment: When  i refreshed the page all color goes default .

Comment: @anor: It won't if you A) Store it correctly when chosen, and B) Retrieve and apply it correctly on page load.

Comment: I saw stored color but it gone when i refreshed the page . So i need something to keep when page refreshed .

Comment: @anor: **Again:** The above does that.

Comment: Ok so problem is ".style.color" part i need to use addClass thanks i will find a way to make it .

Comment: @anor: No, you don't have to use classes, that was just the easy thing to do in my example. Thinking about it, my example may be over-complicated. (That said, classes are usually a good idea wrt styling.)

Comment: localStorage.setItem("color." + id, '#ffffff');
    var theirColor = localStorage.getItem("color." + id);
    document.getElementById('a.'+id).style.color= theirColor;

Comment: when i refreshed the page  . I saw default color . My function is inside of a onclick event btw .